# Как использовать оператор in в lambda-функции? python

Tags: python, pandas

Уважаемые знатоки Python, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с языком начинающему аналитику!

Задача: есть огромный список городов (6к+), в который затесались  названия улиц, и совхозов и т.д. Хочу оставить только крупные города, а для остальных написать "другие".

Решила начать с малого, чтобы проверить работоспособность функции:

```
data['big_city'] = data['city'].apply(lambda x: 'другие' if 'имени' in x)
```

Выдает `InvalidSyntax`. Никак не пойму, в чем проблема.

Пробовала через **def**, но тогда выдает

> ```
> TypeError: argument of type float is not iterable.
> ```

Хотя у меня строковые значения, и цифр там вообще нет.

Comment: `lambda x: 'другие' if 'имени' in x else 'что-то другое'`

Comment: Тогда снова выдает TypeError: argument of type float is not iterable :(

Comment: Не реально дать адекватный ответ без образца того что вы пытаетесь обработать

Comment: 1) кто такая ваша `data` ? 2) полный traceback, пожалуйста. 3) [example]

Comment: Если это датафрейм pandas, приведите в текстовом виде пример исходных данных и выставьте в вопросе соответствующие теги.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TypeError: argument of type **float** is **not iterable**.

Скорее всего у вас в данных есть `NaN`, а `NaN` в `Pandas`/`Numpy` имеет тип `float`. Соответственно конструкция `'имени' in x`, где `x` имеет тип `float` приводит к такой вот ошибке. Вам нужно что-то сделать с `NaN`, например, поменять их на пустую строку перед `apply` через `.fillna`, ну и учесть комментарии и ответы насчёт того, что тернарный оператор обязательно должен иметь ещё часть `else`. Но вообще такая задача как ваша может решаться и по-другому:

```py
# сначала копируем все города
data['big_city'] = data['city']
# а потом заменяем те, где есть 'имени' на 'другие'
data.loc[data['city'].str.contains('имени'), 'big_city'] = 'другие'
```

Возможно, в этом варианте что-то тоже придётся делать с `NaN`, для этого у `str.contains` есть параметр `na=`, где можно указать, какое значение считать за `NA`.

Comment: Точно! Все получилось, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

1. Как вы определите, какой город большой? Вы это не сказали. Например у вас может быть список `big_cities`.
2. Ваше выражение `'другие' if 'имени' in x` неправильно. Здесь должна обязательно быть тоже ветвь `else`.

Значит, правильное выражение теперь будет выглядеть так:

```
data['big_city'] = data['city'].apply(lambda x: 'другие' if x not in big_cities else x)
```

---

*Тест:*

```
>>> data
              city
0      Новосибирск
1        Раменское
2           Москва
3          Назрань
4         Ноябрьск
5  Санкт-Петербург
 
>>> big_cities
['Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Новосибирск', 'Екатеринбург']

>>> data['big_city'] = data['city'].apply(lambda x: 'другие' if x not in big_cities else x)
>>> data
               city         big_city
 0      Новосибирск      Новосибирск
 1        Раменское           другие
 2           Москва           Москва
 3          Назрань           другие
 4         Ноябрьск           другие
 5  Санкт-Петербург  Санкт-Петербург
```